# Do I need to define some constructor in my class to enable assignment with `{}`

Tags: c++, constructor, list-initialization

From C++11 and above, I can construct a class with list initialization `std::vector<int> foo{1,2,3}` or copy list-initialization with `std::vector<int> foo = {1,2,3}`. Assuming I have a class as follows

```
class Bar {
};
class Event{
public:
 int time;
 Bar* ptr;
 Event() = default;
 Event(int t, Bar* p):time(t),ptr(p){};
};
```

I don't know why the following code compiles, given that I have not overloaded any `=` , neither defined any specific constructor except the two in the `Event` class.

```
Event e1 = {1, nullptr}; // compiles, why e1 can be assigned a value with {} given it is not an aggregate type
// --------------------
std::map<int, Event> mp;
mp[1] = {1, nullptr}; // compiles, same confusion, why I can use curly braces to assign?
```

Comment: Did you try making everything public? (a `struct` in effect)

Comment: Have you tried compiling the code? Typos aside, the only reason this doesn't work is because the constructors are private.

Comment: Those are two different kinds of initialization.

Comment: Sorry, I did not compile it, just want to show as an example

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Yes, assuming all public

Comment: First of all included code has lots of stupid mistakes. Second problem fixing those mistakes passes all required uses cases: https://godbolt.org/z/6Trh75GWh so please make sure you understand what initialization list is and what is brace initialization and specify your use case of construction more clearly.

Comment: BTW if I try fill the blanks in your question and try introduce initializer list memory management issue pops up because of existing code.

Comment: @MarekR I revised my question to make it more specific. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are confusing the idea between [List initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) and [Aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).
While **aggregate initialization** is a form of **list initialization**, **list initialization** often refers to the initialization that uses `std::initializer_list`, which is introduced in C++11.

**List initialization** can often be used to simplify the creation of a member container. To create a constructor that uses `std::initializer_list`, you would do:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    std::vector<int> vec;

    Foo(std::initializer_list<int> li)
    : vec(li)
    {}
};
```

And now you can create a `Foo` with: `Foo foo{1,2,3,4,5}` or `Foo foo = {1,2,3,4,5}`.

`std::initializer_list` also has the `begin()` and `end()` iterator, so you can access the member through for-loops if needed. However, do notice that it does not have a bracket accessor `operator[]`, and it must be monotype, which means it is not applicable in your case.

---

Instead what you are looking for is **aggregate initialization**. To enable **aggregate initialization**, all you need is to make sure all members are public visible, and you do not have a user declared constructor:

```cpp
class Event{
public:
    int time;
    Bar* ptr;
};
```

Now you can aggregate initialize a `Event` with the syntax you wanted:

```cpp
Event e1 = {1, nullptr};
Event e2{1, nullptr};
```

---

Optionally, you can provide default values for each member:

```cpp
class Event{
public:
    int time = 0;
    Bar* ptr = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    Event e1;        // e1.time defaulted to 0, e1.ptr defaulted to nullptr
    Event e2{5};     // e2.ptr defaulted to nullptr
}
```

Without the default value, doing `Event e1;` could make `e1.time` and `e1.ptr` be potentially undefined.

Comment: Thanks, now I am clear about aggregate initialization. But how should we interpret the following code given the exact original code context: `std::map<long, Event> mp; mp[1] = {1, nullptr};`-->it can compile.  I thought it should have a compilation error. Why I can assign {1, nullptr} to mp[1] given that I haven't overloaded `=` and Event is not an aggregate type.

Answer (score 0):

After read some references carefully, I kind of have a better understanding on this topic. Not 100% sure but my understanding is as follows:

`Event e1 = {1, nullptr}`  is **[copy list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), item (6).** The compiler will find a constructor that match the given parameters in the `{}`. Note this is not [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) even though they have the same form (using curly braces).

`mp[1] = {1, nullptr}` is also **[copy list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), item (6)** because the `Event` does not overload `=` (so **item (10)** does not apply, right?).

Answer (score -2):

You can use varargs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    template <class... T>
    Foo(T... a) {
        std::cout << "List initialization." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int, char **) {
    Foo foo{1,2,3};
}
```

Then see this page for more info: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic

Comment: That's not a variadic function, it's using [Parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)